# Custom Floating or fixed scrollbar/DIV bar

Tags: javascript, css

I have a DIV on my webpage which is a set width, say 1300px wide. Inside this I have a HTML table which has a width that sometimes exceeds that of the parent DIV. It depends how long some of the data in each column is.

Easy answer is overflow-x: auto or scroll.

The issue is; the scroll bar is at the bottom of the DIV and if my table is 50+ rows tall it's a bad user experience as users may not notice columns are hidden and there's a scrollbar at the bottom of the page.

I've spent some considerable time on google. I can't find anything.

Is there a way of loading a semi transparent bar (DIV) or custom scroll bar that to somehow overlay my table to users can move it and scroll left to right and view all of the table data?

Thinking either JS or CSS most likely both.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Sure, here's a mini example: https://jsfiddle.net/cysrwhxn/3/

Comment: Please clarify this line _Is there a way of loading a semi transparent bar (DIV) or custom scroll bar that to somehow overlay my table to users can move it and scroll left to right and view all of the table data?_. Any visualization of what you want?

Comment: Looks stupid, but like this, but functions like a scroll bar - https://jsfiddle.net/cysrwhxn/5/